# Split text from bash variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a variable which has groups of numbers. It looks like this:

```
foo 3
foo 5
foo 2
bar 8
bar 8
baz 2
qux 3
qux 5
...
```

I would like to split this data so I can work on one 'group' at a time. I feel this would be achievable with a loop somehow. The end goal is to take the mean of each group, such that I could have:

```
foo 3.33
bar 8.50
baz 5.00
qux 4.00
...
```

This mean taking has been implemented already, but I've brought it up so the context is known.

It's important to note that each group (eg. foo, bar, baz) is of arbitrary length.

How would I go about splitting up these groups?

Comment: While this has been answered, I just found a question (at time of writing is six months old) which is duplicate to mine at this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465811/awk-to-average-column-based-on-key-in-2nd-column?noredirect=1 sorry guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `awk` (tested using the GNU version `gawk` here, but I *think* it's portable) for both the collecting and the averaging. As a coreutil, it should be in just about anything `bash` is installed on.

```
# print_avg.awk
{
    sums[$1] += $2
    counts[$1] += 1
}
END {
    for (key in sums)
        print key , sums[key] / counts[key]
}
```

data.txt:

```
foo 3
foo 5
bar 8
bar 8
baz 2
qux 3
qux 5
```

Run it like:

```
$ awk -f print_avg.awk data.txt 
foo 4
baz 2
qux 4
bar 8
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention Linux at all; but indeed, Awk should exist in anything even remotely Unix-like, with the possible exception of some very spare embedded environments.